# What is the recommended guideline to show a disabled tile in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

In a metro app I want to show some tiles as disabled. That is the user can see them but should be able to distinguish that the particular section is disabled and will only be enabled for subscribed users or will be enabled when some other conditions are met.

What is the guideline to design such a thing? Should I use a grayish tile to give the impression that it is disabled?

Most of the discussions are around "how to disable live tiles" when I search for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers to this may be largely subjective, but here's my $0.02 on what you may want to consider.

AFAIK, there isn't such a thing as a disabled tile in terms of the Windows 8 Start Screen.  Perhaps the closest analog is an app that you obtained via a trial, and that trial has now ended.  In that case, the tile will show with an X glyph, but you will be still able to launch it.  "Launching" though brings you to the Windows Store page to buy the app - the only logical action for the current state.

If you use that as your pattern then you'd be consistent with the Start Screen experience, but I don't think you necessarily have to be. People are probably more conditioned, as you mention, to seeing a muted, grayish tile indicating 'disabled.'  Is that enough? Does it pass accessibility guidelines (distinguishing on color alone?) - you may need more, like a glyph, different outlining, etc.

As a user, I lean toward wanting the tile always doing something, perhaps even quite subtle, to indicate it's alive (or could be) - perhaps just a tiny animation so that the user has feedback that the element was hit, but not fully available in the current context.  In addition, at least as a new user to the application, I would want to know why exactly that item isn't available and how I might make it available.  For the Start Screen, the unavailable tile takes you to the Store to buy the app; in your case, what information can you provide to inform the user of why that tile is disabled?  You could perhaps do a lightweight flyout that explains why (or even hover text), and maybe include an option "don't show this again" so experienced users don't get annoyed.

It sounds like a great scenario for usability and A/B testing among your potential user base.

One other thought came to mind.. check out some of the apps in the store that have free trials, and see how they 'disable' premium content.  They may or may not use something like tiles, but you'd get some different perspectives on how other developers are handling a similar scenario, and you may find one approach or another more in line with your goals.